# Python directory walker pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt4

I am trying to write a directory walker in python that determines to find a file type. My problem is that I may have a reference to the parent folder in my sub folder resulting in a loop. Is there any way I can overcome this problem ? My code looks like so:

```
def _hasMp3(path, fileTypes):
   if path:
     childDirs = [root]
     fileTypes = fileTypes or []
     while childDirs:
        qdir = childDirs.pop()
        path = unicode(qdir.absolutePath())
        path = os.path.normalpath(path)
    return False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the resolved path of each directory and keep a set of all those seen before:

```
 seen = set()
 while subDirs:
    qdir = subDirs.pop()
    path = unicode(qdir.canonicalPath())
    if path in seen:
        continue
    seen.add(path)
```